# import functionalities wrapped in an object in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I try to do the following syntax: Given a library with functionalities `import {paint, work, drink} from actions`, how can I do something like the below? I tried, but it gives the error log `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paint')`.

```
import acts from actions

acts.drink();
acts.work();
acts.paint();
```

The example follows with a library [arqeo](https://github.com/trouchet/arqeo) (I wrote, nice to meet you :-) ): As you can see on [example folder](https://github.com/trouchet/arqeo/blob/main/example/esmodule/index.js), I do as follows. I am not sure why does it work, but the example runs normally.

```
import aqo from "arqeo"

const { is, are, has, catalog, apply, pick, curate } = aqo;
```

I am almost sure that the syntax below works well.

```
import * as acts from "actions"

acts.drink();
acts.work();
acts.paint();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing named and default exports.

If you are using CommonJS then change your export code in actions to

```
module.exports = {paint, work, drink}
```

If you are using ES6 then change your export code in actions to

```
export default {paint, work, drink}
```

Now, use actions as described below in your file where you were getting TypeError.

```
import acts from 'path-to-your-actions-file'

acts.drink();
acts.work();
acts.paint();
```

Comment: I editted the OP content to reflect the use case I describe. You may check the file `index.js` of referred library 'arqeo' here https://github.com/trouchet/arqeo/blob/main/src/index.js . I think, that I can solve this question with `export default { is, are, has, catalog, apply, pick, curate }` . What do you think?